# I want to Post a Json Object of given format in windows phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, serialization, windows-phone-8

Earlier I used to make object like:

```
JObject json = new JObject(
                     new JProperty("user", user,
                     new JProperty("credit", credit),                         
                     new JProperty("name", name)
                   );
```

But in this case I want a loop inside the When I am making the Json Object and for its formatting I was using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, jsSettings)` but I find `\` and `/` slashes and the format what I needed is not in that format.

```
Json Format :

{  
    "user":some value  
    "credit":some value  
    "data":[  
        { "friend":some value  
           "friend_list:some value"  
        },  
        {},..  
    ]  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataContractJsonSerializer and [json2Csharp](http://json2csharp.com/#) to parse  json object
here are the small example, that may help you.

```
  MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString));
    DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
   //here are the parse data 
RootObject itemDataList = dataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(memoryStream) as RootObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use : http://james.newtonking.com/json the best json library then try this example

Product p1 = new Product
 {
   Name = "Product 1",
   Price = 99.95m,
   ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2000, 12, 29, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
 };
 Product p2 = new Product
 {
   Name = "Product 2",
  Price = 12.50m,
  ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2009, 7, 31, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
};

List products = new List();
products.Add(p1);
products.Add(p2);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products, Formatting.Indented);

for more reference you can check this link : http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html

Comment: No by doing this i am getting the json as {/"friend_list"\/\some value then some backslashes }